# Error while importing Training class in Google Prediction API

Tags: java, google-client, google-prediction

I'm trying to run [PredictionSample](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/prediction-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/prediction/cmdline/PredictionSample.java) in google-api-java-client-samples. But I get import error. Project can't find Training.java file in google client library. I have imported all the required libraries and included in class path.

[image]

Here I get error.

[image]

I tried in google to find similar situation but only found one unresolved question.

So where did I miss? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salutations,

Looks like the [com.google.api.services.prediction.model.Training](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/prediction/v1.5/java/latest/overview-tree.html) was removed in [v1.6](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/prediction/v1.6/java/latest/overview-tree.html). Try using the [v1.5 version](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-prediction/v1.5-rev55-1.19.0) of the library.